# Downloadable Package Static Content used in a web application

Tags: performance, browser

We have a simulation web application which runs completely within a browser. This simulation requires a large number of static files (JS, CSS, Images) to be downloaded. The size for specific simulation packages runs into a few Megabytes. Even though the files are getting cached, the first time load experience for a user on a slow network is quite poor. The simulations are taken in a testing scenario where they need to take the test at a stipulated time of the day, so it becomes a problem for them.

How can we provide the static resources as a downloadable package which can be pumped into the browser cache of their computer beforehand? Downloading the resources as a package is easy, how does one push them into the cache so that they are recognized and used by the browser instead of downloading them from the server?

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest is - as far as I know - not possible. It would create a huge security hole - if a user loaded arbitrary files into their browser cache to be rendered in the context of a web request, it would allow an attacker to spoof all sorts of things - e.g. inject JavaScript to redirect users to a phishing site if they can upload JS which pretends to be part of a banking website.

There are a number of things you can do to speed up that initial hit with the assets - [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) will give you many useful hints.